# When using a functional component, why do parent state changes cause child to re-render even if context value doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm switching a project from class components over to functional components and hit an issue when using a context.

I have a parent layout that contains a nav menu that opens and closes (via state change in parent). This layout component also contains a user property which I pass via context.

Everything worked great before switching to the functional components and hooks.

The problem I am seeing now is that when nav menu is opened from the layout component (parent), it is causing the child component to re-render. I would expect this behavior if the context changed, but it hasnt. This is also only happening when adding useContext into the child.

I'm exporting the children with memo and also tried to wrap a container with the children with memo but it did not help (actually it seemed to cause even more renders).

Here is an outline of the code:

*AppContext.tsx*

```
export interface IAppContext {
    user?: IUser;
}

export const AppContext = React.createContext<IAppContext>({});
```

*routes.tsx*

```
...
export const routes = <Layout>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/metrics' component={Metrics} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
</Layout>;
```

Layout.tsx

```
...

const NavItems: any[] = [
    { route: "/metrics", name: "Metrics" }
];


export function Layout({ children }) {
    const aborter = new AbortController();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState<IUser>(null);
    const [navOpen, setNavOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    const [locationPath, setLocationPath] = React.useState<string>(location.pathname);
    const contextValue = {
        user
    };

    const closeNav = () => {
        if (navOpen)
            setNavOpen(false);
    };

    const cycleNav = () => {
        setNavOpen(prev => !prev);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        Fetch.get("/api/GetUser", "json", aborter.signal)
            .then((user) => !aborter.signal.aborted && !!user && setUser(user))
            .catch(err => err.name !== 'AbortError' && console.error('Error: ', err));

        return () => {
            aborter.abort();
        }
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        return history.listen((location) => {
            if (location.pathname != locationPath)
                setLocationPath(location.pathname);
        })
    }, [history]);

    const navLinks = NavItems.map((nav, i) => <li key={i}><Link to={nav.route} onClick={closeNav}>{nav.name}</Link></li>);

    return (
        <div className="main-wrapper layout-grid">
                <header>
                    <div className="header-bar">
                        <div className="header-content">
                            <div className="mobile-links-wrapper">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div className="mobile-nav-bars" onClick={cycleNav}>
                                            <Icon iconName="GlobalNavButton" />
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Collapse className="mobile-nav" isOpen={navOpen}>
                        <ul>
                            {navLinks}
                        </ul>
                    </Collapse>
                </header>            
            <AppContext.Provider value={contextValue} >
                <main role="main">
                    {children}
                </main>
            </AppContext.Provider>
            <a target="_blank" id="hidden-download" style={{ display: "none" }}></a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

*Metrics.tsx*

```
...
function Metrics() {
   //Adding this causes re-renders, regardless if I use it
   const { user } = React.useContext(AppContext);
...
}

export default React.memo(Metrics);
```

Is there something I am missing? How can I get the metrics component to stop rendering when the navOpen state in the layout component changes?

Ive tried memo with the switch in the router and around the  block. I've also tried moving the contextprovider with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your `Layout` component renders, it creates a new object for the `contextValue`:

```js
const contextValue = {
    user
};
```

Since the `Layout` component re-renders when you change the navigation state, this causes the context value to change to the newly created object and triggers any components depending on that context to re-render.

To resolve this, you could memoize the `contextValue` based on the `user` changing via a `useMemo` hook and that should eliminate the rendering in `Metrics` when the nav state changes:

```
const contextValue = React.useMemo(() => ({
   user
}), [user]);
```

Alternatively, if you don't really need the object, you could simply pass the `user` as the context value directly:

```
<AppContext.Provider value={user}>
```

And then access it like:

```js
const user = React.useContext(AppContext);
```

That should accomplish the same thing from an unnecessary re-rendering point of view without the need for `useMemo`.

Comment: Perfect! After hours of trying, both of these suggestions worked like a charm. Thank you!